# Timber + Gutenberg ACF Blocks doesnt rendering front end

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

here is my Class what extend on Timber Site class.

```
<?php 

    class EngineACF  extends Timber\Site {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            add_action( 'admin_head' , [$this, 'adminStyle']);
            add_action( 'acf/init', [$this, 'acfBlocks'] );
        }   

        /**
         * Define Gutenberg Blocks
         * @version 1.0
         */

        public function acfBlocks()
        {
            if (!function_exists( 'acf_register_block' )) {
                return;
            }

            $blocks = [
                [
                    'name' => 'homepage-slider',
                    'title' => 'Homepage Slider'
                ]
            ];

            foreach ($blocks as $perKey => $perBlock) {
                acf_register_block(
                    [
                        'name'            => data_get($perBlock, 'name'),
                        'title'           => data_get($perBlock, 'title'),
                        'description'     => data_get($perBlock, 'title'),
                        'render_callback' => [$this, 'renderAcfCallback'],
                        'category'        => 'formatting',
                        'icon'            => 'format-aside',
                        'keywords'        => [str_replace(' ', ',', data_get($perBlock, 'name'))],
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Render Dynamic Gutenberg block template
         * @version 1.0
         */

        public function renderAcfCallback( $block, $content = '', $is_preview = false ) {
            
            $blockName = data_get($block, 'name');

            $blockName = str_replace('acf/', '', $blockName); 
            $context                = Timber::context();
            $context['block']       = $block;
            $context['fields']      = get_fields();
            $context['is_preview']  = $is_preview;
 
            Timber::render( 'blocks/'.$blockName.'-block.twig', $context );
        }
 
    }
```

I also have, blocks/homepage-slider-block.twig file.
In admin panel, with gutenberg editor everything works perfectly. But in frontend, post content doesn't work/render correctly.

Any helps ?
Thanks.

The output like :

[image: frontend output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright. I just found what the issue was.
I was using the `post.post_content` variable from twig.

**Apparently that is not a variable that contains the final content**.

For **future** reference for people with something like this issue:
Use the `{{post.content}}` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar behavior by calling `$context['post'] = get_post();`  - this is the incorrect way I guess.  Should be calling `$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();`.  Then as you stated, use `{{post.content}}` which also eliminates all the dirty wp:paragraph etc comments.

Comment: i really got you but that point was about, acf rendered content.